# How to execute a stored proc in C# the easy way?

Tags: .net, stored-procedures

Usually when I execute a stored proc from C# (ASP.NET 3.5), I have to do the following:

```
myConnection.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = myConnection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "myProc";

SqlParameter param1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.VarChar);
param1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
param1.Value = txtParam.Text;

SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Is there a way to create a C# class that is somewhat polymorphic that can handle calling a proc like you would a function? (ex. `Procs.myProc(param1)`)

Comment: Not really, its up to the developer here to provide some abstraction. Most people (myself included) create wrapper methods.

I.e public List<Foo> GetFoos(string foo, int bar)

The method would then do the above code for you (create/dispose connection, set params, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can really cutback on the # of lines of code by implementing the [Enterprise Library.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648951.aspx).

Comment: And with EntLib5 DAB, I'm almost jealous of how easy they made things if you write stored procs... almost.

Answer (score 0):

You can either write your own helper class to do all that work (open/close connections, etc) so that you only have to pass the name of the procedure and pareameters and get whatever on the other side (reader, dataset, etc...) or you can use a third party tool that does that for you (and heaps more) like Subsonic:

[http://geekswithblogs.net/scottkuhl/archive/2006/12/08/100700.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20150713072104/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/scottkuhl/archive/2006/12/08/100700.aspx)