# Call SQL stored procedure in C# (Windows Application)

Tags: c#, sql-server

I tried to Rank Students based on Average of 3 subject marks. The stored procedure that have been created allots rank by average of 3 subjects. I have also created a C# Windows Application to insert, update, delete and view. When it was in form of SQL table it worked without getting rank but now I have converted to a stored procedure along with Rank column. My need is when I enter the values in Windows Application Form it must view with Rank.

I hope my question is clear.

Comment: Simply set the [SqlCommand.CommandType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) of your SqlCommand to [CommandType.StoredProcedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.commandtype?view=net-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)

Comment: Just follow the links from the MS documentation - plenty of sample code there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute a stored proc in C# the easy way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154177/how-to-execute-a-stored-proc-in-c-sharp-the-easy-way)

Comment: No, your question is completely unclear... in fact you don't appear to have asked on. What exactly are you asking for help with?

Comment: OK, you have posted a bunch of code that looks like it does some of that, what does/doesn't your existing code do... what are you stuck? Don't make us try and read through your code to make sense of it, tell us where you are stuck.

Comment: Side notes: You should dispose your connection and command objects with `using`. Do NOT inject data into your queries, use proper parameterization. Your stored procedure doesn't make much sense: you only have a single row in the `student01` table you are querying, and even if you had more, this could all be done in a single query, no temp tables or `update`s needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly modify your code using the following :

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Student11", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```